# PyScript Unable to install '*-py3-none-any.whl'

Tags: python, pyscript

FULL ERROR:
(PY1001): Unable to install package(s) 'python_aternos-2.1.3-py3-none-any.whl'. Reason: Can't find a pure Python 3 Wheel for package(s) 'python_aternos-2.1.3-py3-none-any.whl'. See: [https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#micropip-can-t-find-a-pure-python-wheel](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#why-can-t-micropip-find-a-pure-python-wheel-for-a-package) for more information.

directory tree:

```
website:
   -index.html
   -python_aternos-2.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <py-config>
            packages = ["python_aternos-2.1.3-py3-none-any.whl"]
        </py-config>
        
        <py-script>
            from python_aternos import Client
            
            #other code
        </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I am trying to make a website with PyScript that uses the python-aternos API.
A previous error message showed me that i need to download a pure python3 wheel file (*-py3-none-any.whl) and import that into the code, but neither does this work.
How can I solve this error? I have been strugling for quite some time...

Comment: Because of the network features in that package, I do not believe it will work in PyScript. Web browsers do not allow direct network activity beyond fetch type of calls.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the browser's development console, one can see that the full error includes the real issue: `ValueError: Can't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'pyjsparser>=2.5.1'.`

(For what it's worth, the fact that PyScript doesn't display the full information is a known issue, being tracked on Github as [Issue #1308](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/1308))